# Docker Https With Azure Key Vault using DevOps Release Pipeline

Tags: azure, docker, https, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

Background:

I am serving an auth server from a normal app service plan and switching to serve the auth server as a docker container. I use CI with dockerfile and azure-pipelines.yaml to push an image to the registry. This triggers my CD which I use Azure Web App on Container Deploy task to deploy. This all seemed fine until I tried to verify my api against an Authorize attribute. It appears that even though I am using a custom domain with https enabled. The tokens generated are still referencing http instead of https.

In order to circumvent this I tried, adding a configuration file or "docker-compose.yaml". However, when I do this my app is breaking. So my two questions are:

-Am I running this correctly to use Https in my docker instance?

-Also, how do I appropriately pass key vault secrets to the docker compose?

Here is my yaml:

```
version: '3.4'
variables:
    - group: VKVAPI
services:
    webapp:
        image: vkv.azurecr.io/vkvauth:latest
        ports:
            - '8000:80'
            - '8001:443'
        environment:
            - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443
            - 'ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+'
            - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=Variable!@#
            - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=$(variable)
```

Also in my log stream I am getting:

```
2020-08-27T23:14:29.758256402Z: [ERROR]  Unhandled exception. Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
2020-08-27T23:14:29.758271702Z: [ERROR]     at Interop.Crypto.CheckValidOpenSslHandle(SafeHandle handle)
2020-08-27T23:14:29.758398002Z: [ERROR]     at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509CertificateReader.FromFile(String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
2020-08-27T23:14:29.758404102Z: [ERROR]     at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
2020-08-27T23:14:29.758408302Z: [ERROR]     at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
2020-08-27T23:14:29.758412302Z: [ERROR]     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelConfigurationLoader.LoadCertificate(CertificateConfig certInfo, String endpointName)
```

Comment: Hi @James,
Is the answer below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Am I running this correctly to use Https in my docker instance?**

There is no problem you run the docker container with HTTPS via the docker-compose. See the details [Starting a container with https support using docker-compose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-compose-https?view=aspnetcore-3.1#starting-a-container-with-https-support-using-docker-compose).

**Also, how do I appropriately pass key vault secrets to the docker compose?**

The possible reason caused the error is the supported [Docker Compose options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container#docker-compose-options) in the Azure Web App for Container does not contain the `variables`. So when you set the variables block and use the variable in it, then it causes the error. I suggest you use the absolute value without the variables.

Comment: It looks then like the docker compose I am using is ok except for the variables? Also, in my dockerfile I am using COPY ["cert.pfx", "/https/cert.pfx"]. This means I can access it then using ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=https/cert.pfx? If so this isn't working for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also I'm not quite sure where to put the certificates and how to use the volumes option appropriately.

Comment: @James As the document shows, the path for the cert cloud be set as you want, just to make sure the cert file exists and can be found. And for you, maybe you need to change the path as `/https/cert.fix`. And for the volumes, you can use the Azure storage account following steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-linux).

Comment: I am trying to narrow down the issue. I have tried multiple ways to get the certificate path but have had no success so far. Would you say that I am set up correctly? And that my only issue would be the certificate path or would there be another issue you can think of?

Comment: @James Do you set the volume correctly? Does it work?

Comment: I set up a storage named vkvapistg with a file named vkv.pfx.  Then on my container instance I added it as a mounted volume named azkvstg, with a mount path of /https. Then on my docker.compose under volumes I put azkvstg:/https and the path was /https/vkv.pfx. I tried multiple combinations with no success. Am I at least on the right path (path as in I may be doing it right but I may be missing some syntax or other)?

Comment: @James Yes, the steps have no problem. Do you set the settings in the Web App config? And do you check the volume inside the container?